# Merge child object value to parent key based on key name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

I have a large nested JSON object which has been auto-generated from an XML schema. This resulted in multiple `children` keys being created and nested within themselves.

The following code snippet describes the nesting.

```json
{
    "attributes" : {
      "name": "xml"
    },
    "children" : [ 
         {
           "children": [
               {
                  "children" :[ 
                       {
                         "attributes":{
                             "min": 1,
                             "max": 2
                          }
                         "children":[1,2,3,4]
                       }
                   ]
               }
            ]
         }
     ]
}
```

I need to move the innermost value of the `children` key to the topmost parent when the nested key names are all `children` without any data loss.

```json
{
    "attributes" : {
      "name": "xml"
    },
    "children" : [ // ** Here
         {
           "children": [
               {
                  "children" :[ // Move this whole array **
                       {
                         "attributes":{
                             "min": 1,
                             "max": 2
                          }
                         "children":[1,2,3,4]
                       }
                   ]
               }
            ]
         }
     ]
}
```

I have tried the following, but this is not working.

```js
function mergeChildToParent(jsonObj) {
  for (const key in jsonObj) {
    if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof jsonObj[key] === "object") {
      if (jsonObj[key].hasOwnProperty("children") && jsonObj[key].value === key) {
        // Push child value to parent and delete child
        jsonObj[key].parentValue = jsonObj[key].value;
        delete jsonObj[key].value;
      }
      mergeChildToParent(jsonObj[key]); // Recurse for nested objects
    }
  }

  return jsonObj;
}
```

Comment: why `if (jsonObj[key].hasOwnProperty("value") ....`? there is no literal `value` property in your object

Comment: Yes , thanks for pointing it out . That should be "children". But I have tried that value and still it is not working @GrafiCode